# what is meaning of Django signed cookie?

Tags: python, django

Is value of signed cookie secure? I supposed that value of signed cookie is encrypting at response and decrypting at request.
[Here is no detail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_signed_cookie) information about it

But when I tried to get value of signed cookie it was visible:

```py
from django.http.response import JsonResponse as J
j = J({})
j.set_signed_cookie("the_key", "the_value")
j.cookies["the_key"].value

> 'the_value:1newi4:nTgUngl_0y6YkqJd711GqMkAQFwXORbug6CdcL_Jo2Q'

j.cookies["the_key"].coded_value

>'the_value:1newi4:nTgUngl_0y6YkqJd711GqMkAQFwXORbug6CdcL_Jo2Q'
```

What is the meaning of `coded_value`? `the_value` is clearly visible in both ways.

Is Django has a some standard way to encrypt cookie value that may be readable only at server side?

- **Edit 1: Add extra question**

According [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signing/) (thanks to `deceze` comment) I'm able to "mask" `the_value`:

```py
from django.core import signing
signer = signing.TimestampSigner()
j.set_signed_cookie("the_key", signer.sign_object('the_value'))

> 'InRoZV92YWx1ZSI:1nex5S:42ra790Q3X-Epn4CsWGe_FJkGfbLcb5GroNw-Hk4Yk8:1nex5S:R9HcGACaH3S0Lr84mt899EzCZAkao_S1pgjjhoMzSZo'
```

But I still not sure is it encrypted value or just serialized and may be simply desirialized at browser side?

And if just serialized →

> Is Django has a some standard way to encrypt cookie value that may be readable only at server side?

Comment: signed means that one can validate that the server is the author of the cookie.

Comment: The explanation is linked right there in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signing/

Comment: Thanks for comments. But I still don't understand is Django allow to encrypt cookie values without writing own encryption algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

A signed cookie is not encrypted. A signature is just a means for an entity to verify the integrity of a value. In this case it is so that the server can ensure that the value in the cookie has not been changed since it was issued. Anyone can read the value, which is the case even in your extra question. This isn't masked, it is just base64 encoded, which is a method used to make it easier for the transmission of bytes.